# correct way to expose a const in javascript using ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

```
const SOME_CONSTANT = 'test case';
class SomeClass {
     static get SOME_CONSTANT(){
         return SOME_CONSTANT;
     }
}
```

Consider this pattern.  This achieves the following two objectives:

1. internally, the item cannot be reassigned
2. externally, the item cannot be reassigned

However, it fails in that it breaks naming conventions for methods - starting with a capital letter is reserved for functions invoked with 'new'.  This trips off an IDE warning in Webstorm.

What is the best way around this ?

Comment: The best way around it is to either ignore your IDE, it's not actually an error, or just rename the god'dam thing. Me personally abhores the whole thing, it just seems so counterintuitive to call a static getter to get a constant variable.

Comment: *"it fails in that it breaks naming conventions for methods"* I'd argue the naming convention primarily exists for the users of the API. However, because this is a getter, the user / caller doesn't even know that this is method. To them it seems like any other non-function property. Better may be `Object.defineProperty(SomeClass, 'SOME_CONSTANT', {value: SOME_CONSTANT});`, which achieves the same thing.